# VS.net 2010 Template and references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

What is the best way to reference DLL (without copying localy into the projet) when creating a project from a "Template" project in VS.net 2010? Because, as known, project template can only make a template for a Project, not solution.

**UPDATE**
My question were not clear :
I want to know how to a project, lets say "Project1", that has few libraries with property "Copy Local" set to false in ASP.net and then use this project as "Template". Referencing DLL in the "project2", the one who use the "project1" as template, is not done properly without bringing each DLL into the project2 directory and recreate the same directory listning as project1. Is there a way to make a template do it all for ya?

Answer (score 1):

A reference DLL won't get copied if it is registered in the GAC.  Trying to avoid the copy for non-GAC-ed assemblies is possible, set the Copy Local property to False.  It is however pretty unusual to do so, you can't debug the code because the CLR cannot find the required assembly at run time.  Not being able to debug code is, well, a problem.

Comment: I don't want to debug it. In my case, the referenced DLL is a Error logging framework that I know it works for now a long time. It's like, if I use a DLL for controls, it is not necesserly into the GAC because once into the Prod server, I've not access to GAC.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Nobody uses a project template and extends it perfectly without ever needing to debug.  And the GAC is *meant* for the deployed version, not the dev version.